# ActiveMQ messages not receive in second consumer

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, activemq-classic

I have implemented `ActiveMQ-Pub/Sub` program using `Java` and `Stomp.js`. There is only one producer that is written in `Java` and consumers are written in `js`.

Here's the problem scenario,

- Producer keep publishes messages to a topic.
- Consumer `A` connects and subscribes the same topic.
- Consumer `B` connects and subscribes the same topic.
- Now `A` and `B` simultaneously listen to same topic, but the data that `A` receives are not same as what `B` receives, `B` skips some data.
- When i disconnect `A`, `B` works fine.
- When i disconnect `B`, `A` works fine.

**Here's Producer code**

```
public static Session SESSION;

/**
 *
 * @return @throws JMSException
 */
public static Session getSessionInstance() throws JMSException, IOException {
    if (null == SESSION) {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(Context.getSystemProperties().getAmp().getUrl());
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connectionFactory.getPrefetchPolicy().setAll(1);
        connection.start();

        SESSION = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }
    return SESSION;
}

/**
 *
 * @param message
 * @throws JMSException
 */
public static void sendMessage(String topic, String message) throws JMSException, IOException {
    Session session = getSessionInstance();
    Destination destination = session.createQueue(topic);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    TextMessage txtMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
    producer.send(txtMessage);

    producer.close();
}
```

**And consumer**

```
var client = Stomp.client("ws://localhost:61614?consumer.prefetchSize=1", "v11.stomp");
client.debug = null;
var selectedVehicleImei = 741852963123456;
client.connect("", "", function (topic) {
    client.subscribe("COO." + selectedVehicleImei, function (message) {
        var infodata = JSON.parse(message.body);
        console.log(infodata);
    })
})
```

i've tried seting `pre-fetch` values as,
in producer,

```
connectionFactory.getPrefetchPolicy().setAll(1);
```

and in consumer,

```
?consumer.prefetchSize=1
```

But still no luck, what's the problem here and can anyone tell me how can i make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use createTopic instead of CreateQueue.  Even though you called the variable topic, it looks like it is a queue.

Queues are for tasks that only need to be answered by one consumer (like sending an email).

Comment: there's a problem, consumers not getting any response and `ActiveMQ admin` displays, two topics i think such as, `COO.355227044952539` and `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.COO.355227044952539` is this possible ?

Comment: is one the destination you created before? (the queue)

Comment: also, there's an queue exists in same name as topic, `COO.355227044952539`

Comment: something is off with the `js` code, when i try subscribing another new topic, it creates a queue that displays in `admin` console

Comment: I wonder if something like `client.subscribe("/topic/COO." + selectedVehicleImei, function (message) {` will work.  The docs say to put in `/queue/` or `/topic/` at the start, but maybe it falls back in `/queue/` if you don't put anything

Comment: do i need to put this prefix in my producer topic too ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would try without first.